# How to load new url request from current loaded WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I have opened WKWebView with "https://www.google.com" for example. Then I'd like to open new url request in the same web view with new link "https://www.youtube.com" for example. I've put listener function to detect for new url and called "webView.load(newURLRequest)". However, the web view is never get loaded with new url request. Can someone help me to suggest solutions please? Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the full codes.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    func reloadWebView(newURLRequest: URLRequest) {
        webView.load(newURLRequest)
    }
}
```

Then, **func reloadWebView(newURLRequest: URLRequest) { ... }** will be called whenever I received new url request from push notification.

Comment: can you add some code snippets that show how you are getting listener event?

Comment: Actually that listener function will be called once received push notification with cloud page embedded. So, once I open the notification, I'd like to refresh the current web view with new url request which is coming from the push notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You can use `NotificationCenter`.
A notification dispatch mechanism that enables the broadcast of information to registered observers.

1. Register the notification in your web view `viewcontroller`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refreshData), name: NSNotification.Name("refreshweb"), object: nil)
}

@objc func refreshData() {
    let url = URL (string: "https://www.youtube.com")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.load(requestObj)
}
```

2. Post the notification whenever you open the notification. (It may be `willPresent notification: UNNotification` or `didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse` in your app delegate)

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("refreshweb"), object: nil)
```

you can pass the received URL from the push notification in the object.

Comment: It didn't allow me to upvote since I don't have enough reputation. :( But of course, just hit for "green right". Thanks again, Shabnam! :D